# Redirect my traffic without changing my domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to redirect my traffic through two regions using cloudfront function, and also select an apigateway depending on the path I receive, currently I have found a way to redirect my traffic but this updates the domain name.

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request
    var path = request.uri;

    var regions = ['us-east-1', 'us-west-2']
    var region = shouldUsePrimaryRegion(regions); 

    var path = path.split('/')[1];

    var  urlToRedirect = 'https://xxxxxxx.default-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stable/v1/multiregion'
    if ((path === 'stable' && region ==='us-east-1'){
       urlToRedirect = 'https://xxxxxxx.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stable/v1/multiregion'
    } 

    if (path === 'stable' && region ==='us-west-2'){
      urlToRedirect = 'https://h7a0xxxxx9.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stable/v1/multiregion'  
    } 

     return {
        statusCode: 302,
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers:  {
            "location": { "value": urlToRedirect }
        }
    };


}
```

what I am looking for is a behavior similar to that of behavior in the distribution, where it evaluates the path and redirects it to the configured origin keeping the domain name. I do not use this solution because of the region selection issue.

Comment: Typically, you'd do this by *proxying* the request, not redirecting.